# C++ Why does sprintf_s format change when used with void pointer?

Tags: c++, printf

This is the working original code:

```
// ...
unsigned __int64 num = 57;
sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%llu", num);
```

However, when I try to extract this part into this function:

```
void addBuffered(void** attributeValue, char* format)
{
    sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, *attributeValue);
}
```

by calling:

```
addBuffered((void**)&num, "%d");
```

I have to change the format parameter in `sprintf_s` from `%llu` to `%d` to get the correct value. Can somebody explain why this happens and if the change of the parameter to `%d` can be a problem? Thanks!

Comment: Probably because your pointers are 32-bit. You're relying on undefined behavior. Don't do it. Use the right format specifier for pointers.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you explain why you must use `void**` instead of just a void pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because `sizeof(void *) == 4` in your case. And you implicitly cast `__int64` to `void *` by function call. So if you use `%llu` format, you print some garbage from memory.

I suggest you to rewrite function if it is possible:

```
template <typename T>
void addBuffered(T *attributeValue, char* format)
{
    sprintf_s(buffer, sizeof(buffer), format, *attributeValue);
}
```

call example:

```
addBuffered(&num, "%luu");
```

Comment: Of course the question becomes, why mix templates and unsafe C-variadics. It's ugly :x

Comment: I agree. Suggest your solution. If it will be good, I'll vote for it.

Comment: Aesthetics aside, sometimes it's simply easier, cleaner and more convenient to use C-variadics and C-style formats.

Comment: Thanks, works great and I don't need to change any existing code

Answer (score 1):

I propose to make it simple:

```
std::ostringstream buffer;

buffer << num;
```

Even though they can be unwieldy for internalization/customization; for simple formatting streams are very simple... and **safe**.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot use ostringstream in my case

Answer (score 0):

You can safely use `%p` as the corresponding `printf` format specifier for values of type `void *`.

Of course, with that said, I'd also recommend you look into a safer implementation here. Is there a reason that your `addBuffered` function isn't variadic? You could potentially use `vsprintf_s` instead.